# When teaching someone how to prove a function is uniformly continuous, using epsilon/delta, which example would be among the simplest?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've taught how to use $\epsilon, \delta$ to prove that a function is continuous at a point, and I'm about to teach how to prove that a function is uniformly continuous over an open interval.

Usually, the examples I can think of that seem easy enough on the outside, require some algebraic trickery that might make it seem more daunting than it needs to be, and may inspire a "damn, this is too difficult" mentality.

Are there some examples of functions that are almost painfully straightforward to give a soft introduction to these, that I may increase the difficulty more smoothly?

Comment: A linear function, perhaps?

Comment: @paw88789 - Definitely a good idea, yeah. Easy, quick, and no long lines of algebra that draw attention away from the end goal. Thanks for the tip! Any natural steps beyond that?

Comment: @Alec In the title question you use the phrase "uniformly continuous", and in the question body you say "prove that a function is continuous over an open interval".  These are different things.  Which did you intend to ask a question about?

Comment: @StevenGubkin - Ah, inaccurate wording on my part. I meant uniformly continuous in both cases.

Answer (score 6):

I think this cannot be understood without a contrasting example where it fails.
So perhaps, in addition to a linear function as suggested by @paw88789, consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ over the open interval $(0,1)$. 
It is continuous over that interval, but not uniformly continuous.
Fix an $\epsilon > 0$; then for any $\delta > 0$ one can
arrange the difference in $f$-values to exceed $\epsilon$ by getting
close enough to $x=0$.

Comment: Also show $1/x$ *is* uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$, or $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$.